# Замена существующих элементов в std::set

Tags: c++

Жили были

```
struct Point {
    double lat;
    double lon;
    time_t when;
};
```

которые хранились в `std::list` (данные изначально сортированы по `when`).
Потребовалось исключение дубликатов по `lat`/`lon`, для чего список был переделан на std::set

```
bool operator < (const Point &point) const {
    return (this->lat < point.lat || this->lon < point.lon) && this->when < point.when;
}
```

Все хорошо, но нужно чтобы не удалялись последующие дубликаты, а перезаписывались старые.

Comment: Первая мысль - использовать `map`, и перезаписывать в духе `m[x] = x`... Формально говоря, у вас ведь не множество - а отображение ключа `lat/lon` на значение `when`. Еще вариант - поиск, удаление и вставка нового?

Comment: Я изменил заголовок — в `std::set` не может быть дубликатов.

Comment: @ixSci так причину изменения вопроса правильнее, имхо, в соответствующее поле описания добавлять при редактировании, а не выносить в коммент :)

Comment: @alexolut, ага, я просто никогда им не пользуюсь. Надо будет привыкнуть к нему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно перезатирать существующие значения в множестве, то перед добавлением (`insert`) в `std::set` нужно проверить наличие такого элемента через `std::set::find`. Если элемент найден, удалить существующий, а после, добавить новый.